# Not deleting node with two children

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

When deleting a node with two children from my binary tree of "products", rather than replacing the root to delete with it's left child's most right ancestor and then deleting that descendant, it is simply just replacing that root's value with ancestors value. I have called "free()" on that ancestor but that doesn't seem to work. So what I am left with is two nodes of the same value.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Structures
typedef struct Node{
    void *dataPtr;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
}node;

typedef struct Product
{
    int ProductCode;
    char ProductName[30];
    int QuantityOnHand;
    double ProductCost;
    double ProductRetail;
    char ProductLocationCode[7];
}product;

//functions

int  compareID(void *ptr1, void *ptr2)
{
    int  temp;

    if (((product *)ptr1)->ProductCode > ((product *)ptr2)->ProductCode)
        temp = 1;
    else
        if (((product *)ptr1)->ProductCode < ((product *)ptr2)->ProductCode)
            temp = -1;
        else
            temp = 0;
    return temp;
}

void insert(node ** root, node** val, int(*f)(void*,void*)){
    if (!(*root)) {

        //initalize a temporary node
        node *temp = NULL;
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

        //make both right and left nodes for temp to be NULL
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;


        temp->dataPtr = (*val)->dataPtr;//store value you were looking for in temp
        *root = temp;// root is now the temporary node
        return;//end of function. 
    }
    int result = f((*root)->dataPtr, (*val)->dataPtr);

    if (result == 1) {//if the value is less than the current root node, go to the left connecting node
        insert(&(*root)->left, &(*val), f);
    }
    else if (result == -1) {//if the value is more than the current root node, go to the right connecting node
        insert(&(*root)->right, &(*val), f);
    }
}

struct Node* deleteNode(struct Node *root, void *ptr, int(*cptr)(void*, void*))
{
    struct Node *temp;

    if (cptr(ptr, root->dataPtr) == 0)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)//no children
        {
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL)//left child
        {
            temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right != NULL)//right child
        {
            temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else //two children
        {
            struct Node* pred = root->left;//go left one of the node you're trying to delete
            while (pred->right != NULL){//now get further right ancestor of that node
                pred = pred->right;
            }

            root->dataPtr = pred->dataPtr; //make the original node the value of that right ancestor
            return pred;//return that ancestor to delete it

        }
    }
    else
    {
        int val = cptr(ptr, root->dataPtr);
        if (val < 0)
        {
            root->left = deleteNode(root->left, ptr, cptr);
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            root->right = deleteNode(root->right, ptr, cptr);
            return root;
        }
    }

}

void readData(struct Node** vptr, FILE *fp){
    product* ptr = (product *)malloc(sizeof(product));
    if (fp == stdin){
        printf("Enter Product Code: ");
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(ptr->ProductCode));
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Enter Name: ");
        fscanf(fp, "%30[^\n]", ptr->ProductName);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Enter Quantity: ");
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(ptr->QuantityOnHand));

        printf("Enter Cost: ");
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &(ptr->ProductCost));
        fflush(stdin);

        ptr->ProductRetail = (ptr->ProductCost / 0.7);

        printf("Enter Location: ");
        fscanf(fp, "%6[^\n]", &(ptr->ProductLocationCode));
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    else{

        fscanf(fp, "%d %29[^\n] %d %lf %6[^\n]", &(ptr->ProductCode), ptr->ProductName, &ptr->QuantityOnHand, &ptr->ProductCost, &ptr->ProductLocationCode);
        ptr->ProductRetail = (ptr->ProductCost / 0.7);
    }
    (*vptr)->dataPtr = ptr;
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    struct Node *newNode, *temp;
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    int(*compPtr)(void *, void *) = compareID;
    for(i; i < 3; i++){
        newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;// missing this operation.
        readData(&newNode, stdin);   //  this function call was missing.
        insert(&root, &newNode, compPtr);
    }

    temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->dataPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Product));

    printf("enter the product ID to delete : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &((struct Product *)temp->dataPtr)->ProductCode);

    deleteNode(root, temp->dataPtr, compPtr);
    free(temp->dataPtr);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this ancestor node not being freed from memory? What should I change in order to make sure it is deleted?

Comment: What has your debugger showed you?

Comment: @StarPilot that when it tries returning the predecor to main, it is not freeing the correct point in memory

Comment: So you see the issue in your debugger. What does your debugger show you for what node is being selected?

Answer (score 1):

Your question and code are confusing at first because you use the word "ancestor" when you mean "descendant." Child nodes are descendants. Ancestors are those that come before.

The problem appears to be that you're *returning* the descendant rather than deleting it. In all the other cases, you're deleting the root and returning the new node. In the case that's causing you trouble, you're not deleting any node. Instead, you're returning the left child's rightmost descendant. The code that calls `deleteNode` replaces the node to be deleted with the node that is returned.

In this case you need to return the root after deleting the node whose value replaced the root's value. But before you can delete that descendant node, you have to remove the link from that node's parent.

I think the code you want is:

```
//go left one of the node you're trying to delete
struct Node* parent = root;
struct Node* pred = root->left;

//now get further right descendant of that node
while (pred->right != NULL){
    parent = pred;
    pred = pred->right;
}

//make the original node the value of that right descendant
root->dataPtr = pred->dataPtr;

// unlink that node from its parent
if (parent == root)
    parent->left = NULL;
else
    parent->right = NULL;

free(pred);
return root; //return the root node
```